# Can't install casperjs on windows

Tags: javascript, windows, casperjs

I followed the instructions in the documentation and when I run the file I get:

> 'casperjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: it may happen because it's path is not found in system variable PATH. to add in path see [this tutorial.](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/36697-how-to-fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows)

Comment: you need to modify step 2 a bit.

Comment: I did the path step, I added: C:\phantomjs;C:\casperjs\bin;C:\Python27

Comment: Have you closed and reopened cmd? Have you tried restarting your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Environment Variable, so that you can use casperjs globally.

Have a look here: [Tuts](http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2014/07/setting-the-system-path-for-casperjs-on-windows#.VT-MECe1Gko)

See, if that works!